# How to use mongodb/mongo-go-driver to perform efficient paging

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query

I read in the following article that it is more efficient to use the natural ordering of `_id` to perform pagination because skip always starts from the beginning of the collection.

[Fast and Efficient Pagination in MongoDB](https://www.codementor.io/arpitbhayani/fast-and-efficient-pagination-in-mongodb-9095flbqr)

```
// Page 1
db.students.find().limit(10)

// Page 2
last_id = ...  # logic to get last_id
db.students.find({'_id': {'$gt': last_id}}).limit(10)
```

But I have no idea how to perform the above using the `mongodb/mongo-go-driver`.

Comment: You gotta try reading the example, its rather not that hard, here https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo . Also, even though mongo-go-driver is the official implementation, try giving a look to `mgo.v2` that is being maintained by GlobalSign, its sort of more convenient, at least to me!

Answer (score 4):

you can create a new func, dont forget to pass http.writer to read parameter.

```
func Pagination(r *http.Request, FindOptions *options.FindOptions) (int64, int64) {
    if r.URL.Query().Get("page") != "" && r.URL.Query().Get("limit") != "" {
        page, _ := strconv.ParseInt(r.URL.Query().Get("page"), 10, 32)
        limit, _ := strconv.ParseInt(r.URL.Query().Get("limit"), 10, 32)
        if page == 1 {
            FindOptions.SetSkip(0)
            FindOptions.SetLimit(limit)
            return page, limit
        }

        FindOptions.SetSkip((page - 1) * limit)
        FindOptions.SetLimit(limit)
        return page, limit

    }
    FindOptions.SetSkip(0)
    FindOptions.SetLimit(0)
    return 0, 0
}
```

just call

```
Pagination(r, options)
```

example

```
options := options.Find()
page, limit := parameter.Pagination(r, options)
// page, limit as response for header payload
```

Answer (score 1):

The [cursor.skip()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/#cursor.skip) method requires the server to scan from the beginning of the input results set before beginning to return results. As the offset increases, cursor.skip() will become slower. While range queries can use indexes to avoid scanning unwanted documents, typically yielding better performance as the offset grows compared to using `cursor.skip()` for pagination. See more information on [MongoDB: Pagination Example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/#pagination-example)

Using the current version of [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) (v0.0.15).An example to perform pagination showing latest entry first:

```
func Paginate(collection *mongo.Collection, startValue objectid.ObjectID, nPerPage int64) ([]bson.Document, *bson.Value, error) {

    // Query range filter using the default indexed _id field. 
    filter := bson.VC.DocumentFromElements(
        bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements(
            "_id",
            bson.EC.ObjectID("$gt", startValue),
        ),
    )

    var opts []findopt.Find
    opts = append(opts, findopt.Sort(bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.Int32("_id", -1))))
    opts = append(opts, findopt.Limit(nPerPage))

    cursor, _ := collection.Find(context.Background(), filter, opts...)

    var lastValue *bson.Value
    var results []bson.Document
    for cursor.Next(context.Background()) {
        elem := bson.NewDocument()
        err := cursor.Decode(elem)
        if err != nil {
            return results, lastValue, err
        }
        results = append(results, *elem)
        lastValue = elem.Lookup("_id")
    }

    return results, lastValue, nil
}
```

An example to call the pagination function above:

```
database := client.Database("databaseName")
collection := database.Collection("collectionName")
startObjectID, _ := objectid.FromHex("5bbafea2b5e14ee3a298fa4a")

// Paginate only the latest 20 documents 
elements, lastID, err := Paginate(collection, startObjectID, 20)
for _, e := range elements {
    fmt.Println(&e)
}
// Last seen ObjectID can be used to call next Paginate() 
fmt.Println("Last seen ObjectID: ", lastID.ObjectID())
```

Note that you can also substitute the `_id` field with another indexed field.

Comment: Sorry for taking to long to respond I don't understand the first half of your response when it talks about `cursor.skip()` I never mentioned any operation in my question that uses the `cursor.skip()` from my understanding?

I don't believe your example is a like for like comparison

Comment: I'm trying to give context on why it's more efficient to not rely on `skip()` as pointed by your first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Set page=0 and limit=0 if no pagination is required.

```golang
func GetUsers (page, limit int) {
    filter := bson.D{{}} // selects all documents
    options := new(options.FindOptions)
    if limit != 0 {
        if page == 0 {
            page = 1
        }
        options.SetSkip(int64((page - 1) * limit))
        options.SetLimit(int64(limit))
    }

    cursor, err := mongoCollection.Find(context.TODO(), filter, options)
...
}
```